# How to turn off a 302 redirect in Azure Websites

Tags: asp.net, azure, ssl, web, redirect

I know this is strange.

I have an azure website. If you visit it, e.g. web1.azurewebsites.net you will be immediately redirected (302) to https://web1.azurewebsites.net

I do not have any code in the deployed application that does, this, nor anything in my web.config.

To test, I created another S1 (i.e. SSL capable) azure websites from scratch, deployed the EXACT same code (even used the same database), and I do not get the redirects.

Where is this 302 redirect setup in Azure?

to be clear. 
1) Exact same code, webconfig etc.
2) only difference is the Azure publish location
3) I do have some recollection of ticking a box somewhere saying 'only allow ssl', but I really can't find it anywhere now.

All references online are a) to turn ssl ON, b) talk about web config and mvc code. Neither apply here due to test.

For you info, in Edge, F12 tools, I can see the redirect under Network tab.
and  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET etc. etc.

I can't find a setting anywhere in Azure portal to turn this off. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to investigate without demo or code. 
If your project doesn't have any rewrite rules then it must be an app service that is doing this.

1. You might have an extension installed that does this: https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2017/01/12/azure-app-service-force-redirect-from-http-to-https-the-easy-way/
2. Or rewrites happen at a higher level. Do you have some kind of service that sits on the top of you app service e.g. cloudflare?
3. You can try clone your existing app (requires premium subscription) to see if the problem is reproduced

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was the browser! not the code....

I had once, at some point put in the HSTS headers for testing. Once you do that in Chrome, it will always 'redirect' itself to the https version.

You can

1. Use incogneto mode
2. clear the 'you must always redirect to https' setting in chrome using the advanced chrome settings.